# Trying to scrape the web from a web page from a separate tab I opened up with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I was able to use selenium to open up a web page in a seperate tab in my Chrome web browser. This web page has a massive table's worth of data I want to grab via beautifulsoup. However, my code generated the following error message. My code is being run on Windows.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
```

Below is the code I have been using.

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import os
import time

```
#Open Webpage
url = "https://www.example.com"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Ben Lutz\Desktop\Ben Lutz\Runway Data Project\Updated Data\New Sheets\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Run').click()
time.sleep(100)
driver.close()

#Scrape Data
df_url = driver.current_url #This is the part of the code that the error is highlighting
page = requests.get(df_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features = 'lxml')
text = soup.get_text()
soup.prettify()

table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
#print(table_rows)

Operations = pd.DataFrame()
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    df_row = pd.DataFrame(row).T
    Operations = Operations.append(df_row.iloc[0])
print(Operations.head)
```

Is there a reason why I'm generating this error? And what should be done to fix this predicament?

Any assistance is truly helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because you call `driver.close()` and then reference `driver.current_url`. After calling `close`, the browser window is closed so there is no browser window for there to a current URL for.

Move `df_url = driver.current_url` above the `driver.close()` line and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You already closed your browser that the reason you are facing issue. Remove driver. close() from your code that causing issue and try after that

`driver. close()` command is used to close the current browser window having focus.